# Customizing the More menu button icon

Tags: android, menu

I was wondering if it is possible to customize the icon used for the More menu option (displayed when there are more than 6 menu options)? With the stock vanilla Android UI it appears as a disclosure-type arrow and on HTC Sense UI it's an ellipsis icon. Curious if these are fixed icons only defined in the Android resources or if there is a way to programmatically set them?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Justin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are system resources - the one you're referring to is android.R.ic_menu_more. I don't know of a way to replace them or have the menu system use a different resource instead.